# Roles in Spring Boot application not working when database auth is used but works if in memory is used

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security

I'm trying to set security roles in my Spring Boot application.

If I use in memory users the roles work. My code looks as folows:

```
@Override
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        
    // add users for in memory authentication
    UserBuilder users = User.withDefaultPasswordEncoder();
        
    auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
        .withUser(users.username("paul").password("test123").roles("MEMBER", "ADMIN"))
        .withUser(users.username("sandra").password("test123").roles("MEMBER", "ADMIN"))
        .withUser(users.username("matthew").password("test123").roles("MEMBER"));
}

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

    http.authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/users/list").hasAnyRole("MEMBER", "ADMIN")
        .antMatchers("/events/list").hasAnyRole("MEMBER", "ADMIN")
        .antMatchers("/events/showFormForAdd").hasRole("ADMIN")
        .antMatchers("/events/listEventAttendeeDetails*").hasRole("ADMIN")
        .antMatchers("/resources/**").permitAll()
        .and()
        .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/showMyLoginPage")
                .loginProcessingUrl("/authenticateTheUser")
                .permitAll();
    }
```

If I use database authentication for `configure()` the user is not authorised to access any pages. My database method looks like this:

```
@Override
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService);    
}
```

As The roles work for in memory and not database I thing the `configure(HttpSecurity http)` must work fine. I suspect there is some issue getting my roles. My User and Authority(roles) models are as follows:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="users")
public class User {
    
    public static final PasswordEncoder PASSWORD_ENCODER = new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="user",
            cascade={CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE,
                    CascadeType.DETACH, CascadeType.REFRESH,
                    CascadeType.REMOVE})
    private List<Authority> authorities;

    // define fields
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="id")
    private int id;

    @Column(name="first_name")
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name="last_name")
    private String lastName;
    
    @Column(name="gender")
    private String gender;
    
    @DateTimeFormat(pattern="yyyy-MM-dd")
    @Column(name="birth_date")
    private LocalDate birthDate;
    
    @Column(name="address_line1")
    private String addressLine1;
    
    @Column(name="address_line2")
    private String addressLine2;
    
    @Column(name="town")
    private String town;
    
    @Column(name="county")
    private String county;
    
    @Column(name="country")
    private String country;
    
    @Column(name="postcode")
    private String postcode;
    
    @Column(name="email")
    private String email;
    
    @Column(name="phone")
    private String phone;
    
    @Column(name="mobile")
    private String mobile;
    
    @Column(name="password")
    private @JsonIgnore String password;
    
    @Column(name="enabled")
    private int enabled;

    // define constructors
    public User() {
        
    }
    
    public User(List<Authority> authorities, int id, String firstName, String lastName, String gender, LocalDate birthDate,
        String addressLine1, String addressLine2, String town, String county, String country, String postcode,
        String email, String phone, String mobile, String password, int enabled) {
        this.authorities = authorities;
        this.id = id;
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.gender = gender;
        this.birthDate = birthDate;
        this.addressLine1 = addressLine1;
        this.addressLine2 = addressLine2;
        this.town = town;
        this.county = county;
        this.country = country;
        this.postcode = postcode;
        this.email = email;
        this.phone = phone;
        this.mobile = mobile;
        this.password = password;
        this.enabled = enabled;
    }
    
    public List<Authority> getAuthorities() {
        return authorities;
    }

    public void setAuthorities(List<Authority> authorities) {
        this.authorities = authorities;
    }
    
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getGender() {
        return gender;
    }

    public void setGender(String gender) {
        this.gender = gender;
    }

    public LocalDate getBirthDate() {
        return birthDate;
    }

    public void setBirthDate(LocalDate birthDate) {
        this.birthDate = birthDate;
    }

    public String getAddressLine1() {
        return addressLine1;
    }

    public void setAddressLine1(String addressLine1) {
        this.addressLine1 = addressLine1;
    }

    public String getAddressLine2() {
        return addressLine2;
    }

    public void setAddressLine2(String addressLine2) {
        this.addressLine2 = addressLine2;
    }

    public String getTown() {
        return town;
    }

    public void setTown(String town) {
        this.town = town;
    }

    public String getCounty() {
        return county;
    }

    public void setCounty(String county) {
        this.county = county;
    }

    public String getCountry() {
        return country;
    }

    public void setCountry(String country) {
        this.country = country;
    }

    public String getPostcode() {
        return postcode;
    }

    public void setPostcode(String postcode) {
        this.postcode = postcode;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getPhone() {
        return phone;
    }

    public void setPhone(String phone) {
        this.phone = phone;
    }

    public String getMobile() {
        return mobile;
    }

    public void setMobile(String mobile) {
        this.mobile = mobile;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = PASSWORD_ENCODER.encode(password);
    }

    public int getEnabled() {
        return enabled;
    }

    public void setEnabled(int enabled) {
        this.enabled = enabled;
    }
    
}


@Entity
@Table(name="authorities")
public class Authority {
    
    @ManyToOne(cascade= {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE,
            CascadeType.DETACH, CascadeType.REFRESH})
    @JoinColumn(name="email")
    private User user;
    
    @Id
    @Column(name="id")
    private String email;

    @Column(name="authority")
    private String authority;
    
    public Authority() {
        
    }

    public Authority(User user, String email, String authority) {
        this.user = user;
        this.email = email;
        this.authority = authority;
    }

    public User getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public void setUser(User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getAuthority() {
        return authority;
    }

    public void setAuthority(String authority) {
        this.authority = authority;
    }

}
```

This is the service I'm using to authenticate:

```
@Service
public class UserDetailsServiceImpl implements UserDetailsService {
    
    @Autowired private UserRepository userRepository = null;

    @Override
    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User user = null;

        try {
            Optional<User> optional = userRepository.findByEmail(username);
            HashSet<GrantedAuthority> set = new HashSet<>();
            /*
             * Add SimpleGrantedAuthority to set as appropriate
             */
            user = new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(username, optional.get().getPassword(), set);
        } catch (UsernameNotFoundException exception) {
            throw exception;
        } catch (Exception exception) {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException(username);
        }

        return user;
    }
}
```

The Authorities are inserted into the DB as follows:

```
INSERT INTO `authorities` 
VALUES 
('john','ROLE_MEMBER'),
('mary','ROLE_MEMBER'),
('mary','ROLE_MANAGER'),
('susan','ROLE_MEMBER'),
('susan','ROLE_ADMIN');
```

I put some logging around UserDetailsServiceImpl. As you can see, no authorities are granted.

```
2020-10-21 17:02:17.612  INFO 20363 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] c.p.clubmanager.aspect.LoggingAspect     : =====> in @Before: Calling method: UserDetailsServiceImpl.loadUserByUsername(..)
2020-10-21 17:02:17.613  INFO 20363 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] c.p.clubmanager.aspect.LoggingAspect     : =====> argument: Paul_carron@hotmail.com
2020-10-21 17:02:17.619  INFO 20363 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] c.p.clubmanager.aspect.LoggingAspect     : =====> in @AfterReturning: from method: UserDetailsServiceImpl.loadUserByUsername(..)
2020-10-21 17:02:17.619  INFO 20363 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] c.p.clubmanager.aspect.LoggingAspect     : =====> result: org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User@eefb770b: Username: Paul_carron@hotmail.com; Password: [PROTECTED]; Enabled: true; AccountNonExpired: true; credentialsNonExpired: true; AccountNonLocked: true; **Not granted any authorities**
```

Is there anything I've done wrong, or may be missing in terms of getting my roles?

Comment: Can you lookup the user you are attempting to authenticate with using UserDetailsServiceImpl and then print it out? What are the authorities? Are they prefixed with ROLE_ if not, then they need to be to conform to the authorization rules you have setup.

Comment: I added the detail to the bottom of the question.

Comment: Are you providing the authorities in your actual code? The sample you have says "Add SimpleGrantedAuthority to set as appropriate" but the authorities (set variable) are never populated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `UserDetailsServiceImpl` it seems that you are setting `Roles/Authority` passing only `new HashSet<>()`. You can try this:

```
try {
    Optional<User> optional = userRepository.findByEmail(username);
    List<SimpleGrantedAuthority> authorities =  set = new ArrayList<>();

    if(optional.isPresent()) {
    authorities = optional.get().getAuthorities().stream()
                                    .map(role -> new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_" + role.getName()))
                                    .collect(Collectors.toList()))
    }
    user = new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(username, optional.get().getPassword(), authorities);
} catch (UsernameNotFoundException exception) {
    throw exception;
} catch (Exception exception) {
    throw new UsernameNotFoundException(username);
}
```